# Will Allah Destroy Us?

Tags: allah, jannah

will Allah (SWT) destroy us completely after  a period of time in jannah or hell?
If yes, does that mean we will be nothing?

Comment: What makes you think of this possibility?

Answer (score 2):

In Islam, Heaven is understood to be a place of everlasting life.

> "But those who have faith and work righteousness, they are companions
>   of the garden. Therein shall they abide forever" ([2:82](https://quran.com/2/82)).

Answer (score 2):

There will be human's eternal life. Allah (SWT) has not created us to destroy us. It's in obvious contradiction with Allah's wisdom and justice.

For further reading refer to [this link](https://www.al-islam.org/rationality-islam-ayatullah-sayyid-abulqasim-al-khui/towards-eternal-life).

Comment: You should support your claims by evidences instead of linking a detailed answer.